# Nested branches, variable depth

Tags: git, git-svn

We have a large, quite old SVN repository that we'd like to migrate to git. Unfortunately, our branch structure is quite tricky; it has nested branches of varying depth, with some branches living alongside nested folders:

```
branches/
         branch1/
         branch2/
         teams/
               team1/
                     projectBranch1
               team2/
                     projectBranch2
```

In my git config, I have tried

```
branches = branches/*/*/*:refs/remotes/origin/*/*/*
```

which has imported the team branches fine, but when fetching updates to "branch1", it treats the first few project directories as part of the branch name, creating branches like `branch1/src/com/`. I then tried:

```
branches = branches/teams/*/*:refs/remotes/origin/teams/*/*
branches = branches/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

hoping that commits to team projects would be matched first, and the first-level wildcard only used for top-level branches. But it then reverts to treating team branches as subdirectories of the "teams" branch. I then hoped reversing the order of the terms in the config file might change the matching order, but that didn't seem to make a difference.

I have managed to get a clean migration from recent revisions by tweaking the top-level wildcard to match only certain names, so that there is no ambiguity between the two `branches` terms. But ideally I'd like to migrate from older revisions, where the top-level branch names are less easily picked out. Is there any way to persuade git-svn to match `branches` entries using a "most specific first" rule?

Comment: *Carefully* re-read https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#_configuration, note (except of sample of complex config) also "It is also possible to fetch a subset of branches or tags by using a comma-separated list of names within braces..." HTH

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, and it's on my list of potential workarounds. Trouble is, this mess is so sprawling, manually specifying branch names will be a major task. If there's some way to force a most-specific-first rule, I could cut that effort down using wildcards. Thanks all the same!

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this? Facing the same issue here with a complex svn-to-git conversion with branches in branches/* and also branches/releases/* etc

Answer (score 1):

I'll recommend to try SubGit for your layout: it can (?) handle [more complex cases](https://subgit.com/documentation/branches-mapping.html#svn_branches), than git-svn

```
branches = branches/*:refs/heads/*
branches = feature_*:refs/heads/features/*
branches = hotfix/*_*:refs/heads/hotfix/*/*
```

Pay attention to wildcard usage on remote and local parts and translations into different namespaces for different paths of svn-branches

even [historical moves and renames](https://subgit.com/documentation/branches-mapping.html#changed_layout)

If I understood your branches tree correctly, i.e. you have at the same time

```
branches/branch*/
…
branches/teams/team*/projectBranch*
```

your SubGit mapping can be something like (TBT!)

```
branches = branches/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branches = teambranches/*-*:refs/remotes/origin/teams/*/*
```